# Socket nodename error with Python Fabric module

Tags: python, sockets, fabric

I am attempting to run a simple command (`ls`) using the `fabric` module by following the examples found in the [fabric documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/getting-started.html). However, when I attempt to call the `run` method on a `Connection` object, I receive

> socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

```
import fabric 
c = fabric.Connection('host')
c.run('ls')
```

I have utilized the `socket` module before, and the error above is generally raised when running `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` to bind a socket to a machine. However, `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` runs without error for me.

How can I successfully use `fabric` to run commands in the shell? As `fabric` utilizes SSH, are there any SSH configurations needed before using `fabric`?

---

I am running `fabric` on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 on Python 3.7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Connection` constructor, you need to give the real host name.

For instance:

```
import fabric

c = fabric.Connection('localhost')
c.run('ls')
```

If the SSH protocole is not configured, you have another error message. For instance:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 127.0.0.1, ::1 or fe80::1%lo0
```

Ofen, the server name is not enough, you need to add the domain name, for instance `myserver.mydomain.com`.